# ¿Como puedo retornar mas de 1 String en una función de JAVA?

Tags: java, mysql, poo

Voy a tratar de ser muy especifico con mi pregunta, tengo las siguientes 3 funciones, que básicamente hacen una búsqueda y cada una retorna algo diferente de una base de datos, los datos que retorna son una URL, USER y PASS, los 3 en conjunto sirven para mandárselos a otra función y establecer una conexión a base de datos:

```
 public String buscarUrl(String nombre,String urldb) throws SQLException{
String sql="SELECT * FROM conect WHERE nombre LIKE '%"+nombre+"%'";
Connection con = Db.connect("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/prueba1", "root", "1234");

try{
PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement(sql);
      ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
      while(rs.next()){
      urldb = (rs.getString("URL"));
     
}
      db.cerrarConexion(); 
}catch(Exception e){JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"No es posible conectarse a la base: " +e);}
return urldb;}

public String buscarUser(String nombre,String passdb*/) throws SQLException{
String sql="SELECT * FROM conect WHERE nombre LIKE '%"+nombre+"%'";
Connection con = Db.connect("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/prueba1", "root", "1234");

try{
PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement(sql);
      ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
      while(rs.next()){
      userdb = (rs.getString("USER"));
      
}
      db.cerrarConexion(); 
}catch(Exception e){JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"No es posible conectarse a la base: " +e);}
return userdb;}

public String buscarPass(String nombre,String passdb) throws SQLException{
String sql="SELECT * FROM conect WHERE nombre LIKE '%"+nombre+"%'";
Connection con = Db.connect("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/prueba1", "root", "1234");

try{
PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement(sql);
      ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
      while(rs.next()){
      passdb = (rs.getString("PASS"));
}
      db.cerrarConexion(); 
}catch(Exception e){JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"No es posible conectarse a la base: " +e);}
return passdb;}
```

}

Como podrán darse cuenta las 3 retornan un valor diferente, yo recibo esos valores de la siguiente manera:

```
 bases bases = new bases(); //En esta clase se ubica mi función.
try {
   url = bases.buscarUrl("PortalDunosusa", url);
    userdb = bases.buscarUser("PortalDunosusa", userdb);
   passdb = bases.buscarPass("PortalDunosusa", passdb);
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(PortalDunosusa.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Una vez recibo esos string los mando a otra función en otra clase la cual me da una conexión a una base de datos dependiendo de los valores que le mande.

```
 Db.connect(url,userdb,passdb)
```

De esa manera mando los valores a esta función:

```
 public class Db {
public static Connection connection;

public static Connection connect(String url,String user,String pass){


try{
     connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user,pass); //Conexión que contiene nuestra
     //URL, USUARIO Y CONTRASEÑA la almacenamos en connection.
   System.out.println("Conectando...");

    
}catch(SQLException e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No es posible conectar con el servidor\n"
    +"por favor intentelo mas tarde  " + e);
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
return connection; //Retornamos la conexión para usarla en otras clases.
}
```

Mi pregunta es, como puedo hacer que en lugar de las 3 primeras funciones en donde me retorna cada una un valor diferente, tener una sola función que me retorne los 3 valores que le solicito, y almacenara cada valor en un String diferente?
no se si me explico, trate de ser lo mas especifico posible.

Comment: simplemente crea un objeto que tenga esos 3 strings, y luego se lo mandas a la otra clase y problema resuelto de una forma simple (salvo que java haya implementado objetos anonimos que permitan que una funcion devuelva mas de una cosa)

Comment: @gbianchi Gracias por responder, la verdad soy muy novato en el tema de la programación, te agradezco de corazón.

Comment: @alexvargas6 Mira fijamente esas tres funciones, tienen el mismo código prácticamente. Lo que cambia es el valor que le pasas al método `getString`, lo que debes hacer, es crear un método que se llame `buscar` y que acepte dos parámetros: `String nombre, String typeSearch`, en el segundo parámetro, le pasas el String, es decir, lo que quieras buscar, que puede ser la URL, user o pass. Y lo que le pasas al parámetro del `getString`, sería el contenido que tenga `typeSearch`. Con esto reutilizas código.

Comment: Un método no puede retornar tres valores, por definición, no. La pregunta es, ¿para que quieres retornar así?

Comment: @MrDave1999 en c# un metodo puede devolver mas de un valor. Un metodo puede devolver 3 valores, si lo que devuelve es un objeto con tres propiedades.. o si devuelve un array ;). Pero no, no puede devolver 3 valores...

Comment: @gbianchi Si el método devuelve un objeto, lo que realmente retornaría sería la dirección base del *objeto* y con eso, ya devuelve únicamente un "valor"..

Comment: por ese hice la aclaracion ;)

Comment: ¿Que tal si en vez de devolver 3 `String` devuelves solo uno con formato, separado por comas (por ejemplo). Luego lo que debes hacer es separarlo en sus componentes y usarlos.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que andas buscando es retornar los 3 valores "juntos" para hacer solamente una consulta. Prueba lo siguiente:

Crea una estructura que te permita guardar los 3 valores:

```
class UserResult {
    private final String url;
    private final String user;
    private final String pass;

    public UserResult(String user, String pass, String url) {
        this.user = user;
        this.pass = pass;
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public String getPass() {
        return pass;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }
}
```

Ahora resume las 3 consultas en 1 solo query que te devuelva los 3 elementos que necesitas y guarda los resultados en una lista de `UserResult` dado que la consulta podría devolverte más de un registro. El método de búsqueda quedaría así:

```
public List<UserResult> buscar(String nombre) throws SQLException {

    List<UserResult> result = new ArrayList<>();

    String sql="SELECT user, pass, url FROM conect WHERE nombre LIKE '%"+nombre+"%'";
    Connection con = Db.connect("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/prueba1", "root", "1234");

    try{
        PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()){
            UserResult ur = new UserResult(
                rs.getString("user"),
                rs.getString("pass"),
                rs.getString("url")
            );
            result.add(ur);
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"No es posible conectarse a la base: " +e);
    } finally {
        db.cerrarConexion();
    }

    return result;
}
```

Y ahora para usarlo solo tienes que hacer esto:

```
bases bases = new bases(); //En esta clase se ubica mi función.
List<UserResult> users = null;
try {
    users = bases.buscar("PortalDunosusa");
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(PortalDunosusa.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Dado que la lista puede contener más de un elemento debes evaluarlo bajo algún criterio para obtener el usuario que necesitas. *Supongamos que es el primero*:

```
if(users != null && !users.isEmpty()) { //La lista no es null ni está vacía
    UserResult ur = users.get(0);
    Db.connect(ur.getUrl(), ur.getUser(), ur.getPass());
}
```